# htaccess adding password while enabling directories view in browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Okay this might be a very obvious one however...

**I have** the following in my .htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Message"
AuthUserFile /www/sites/5ce/448/domainname/folder.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Which works fine for password protecting the folder it's placed in.

**I also have** in another .htaccess file (when I remove the first one)

```
Options +indexes
```

Which works fine for showing the directory folder and included files on browser.

When I put these together i get Error 500. How do you essentially enable directory view but password protected?

Comment: May you edit your question with your actual not working code ?

Comment: Are there any interesting informations in the error.log file ?

Comment: @AdrienLeber Okay this was reallyyyyyy stupid. It was just the incorrect directory for .htpasswd (different hosting directory). Thanks for your help. I have to remember to look at the most basic things first. :@ !

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck. ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space between the `+` and the `indexes`.
Try this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Message"
AuthUserFile /www/sites/5ce/448/domainname/folder.htpasswd
require valid-user
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: thanks for your response. There was not a space, just my question became edited like that. Basically it does not work together, but they work separately

Comment: My bad for the space. It becomes like this while edition. @Michael, note the capital `I` for `+Indexes`.

Comment: @AdrienLeber no problem, I tried captial I also, same issue. Error 500. Maybe to do with permissions?

Comment: @Michael still with the 500 ? Maybe you're not allowed to override Options. The code provided by Dekel works well.

Comment: @AdrienLeber yeah still 500. overriding options works without applying the password though. hmmm